# Is there a way to use CV-Bridge within conda virtual environment with ROS-Noetic?

Tags: tensorflow, ros, virtual-environment

Currently, I am working on a project requiring Tensorflow to be used for Object Detection for ROS. I have installed ros-noetic using 'sudo' commands, and then created my Tensorflow environment based on the tutorial ([linked](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)).

After solving other dependency problems necessary to run a launch file to spawn a urdf within Gazebo, I was able to do so *within* the Tensorflow virtual environment.

The problem I am facing is now with CV-Bridge. When I am within my virtual environment, running the following command gives the following error (listed below)

The same problem doesn't persist when I am outside of the virtual environment. I am wondering if there is a way to correct this issue so I can use cv-bridge within the conda environment as I need to do some processing of images that I am subscribed to using Tensorflow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

from cv_bridge.boost.cv_bridge_boost import getCvType

ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. My python version is 3.8.16. It requires libffi above 3.4. At this time , it would use libffi.so.8.xx. That is the reason of error. So I downgraded the python version to 3.8.10 and run my program normally.